# powershell copy disk excluding particular file types

Tags: file, powershell, copy

I am working on a PowerShell 2 script that will read a CD-ROM or DVD disk and copy its contents - the caveat is that I need to check for certain file types and NOT copy anything over with that filetype.  So far I have this working:

```
$user = read-host "Enter owner's username:"
$drv = read-host "Enter Optical Drive letter (no colons or slashes):"

$list = Import-Csv badtypes.csv
$badlist = @()
$Extns = @()

ForEach($xt in $list)
{
    $Extns += "."_$xt.Extention
}

$filepath = $drv +":\"
$cnts = Get-ChildItem $filepath -r

ForEach($itm in $cnts)
{
   if($itm.PSis.Container)
   {
       #write new folder name in user's temporary folder
   }
   else
   {
       CheckFile $itm
   }
}

Function CheckFile($fl)
{
    $fildextension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtention($fl)

    $badfound = 0

    ForEach($a in $Extns)
    {
        if($a -eq $fildextension)
        {
           $badfound = 1
        }
    }

    if(badfound -eq 0)
    {
       write-host "File Type Acceptable:" $fl
       # write file to proper place in the user's temporary folder 
    }
}
```

I'm having a problem getting the an empty folder created in the proper place and copying the (acceptable) file to the proper place.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered using ROBOCOPY for this? It's highly configurable, returns usable exit codes and log files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticking with a powershell solution, try this on for size:

```
$user = read-host "Enter owner's username:"
$drv = read-host "Enter Optical Drive letter (no colons or slashes):"

$list = Import-Csv badtypes.csv
$Exclusions = "*.$($list.Extension -join ",*.")"
$DestFolder = New-Item -path "\\BAAC\homedir\$user\transfer\$(get-date -f MMddyyyy.HH.mm)"  -ItemType Directory
$FilePath = $drv +":\"

Write-Host "Copying files from $FilePath to $DestFolder`:"

Copy-Item "$FilePath*" -Destination $DestFolder -Exclude $Exclusions -Recurse -PassThru
explorer $DestFolder
```

Don't really need the user's name, but I left it in there. Here's what the script will do:

- It gets the drive letter
- Imports the list of extensions to exclude, builds a string from them (resultant string would be something like "`*.bat,*.exe,*.com`" if your CSV had 3 entries being bat, exe, and com).
- It creates a date/time formatted folder in the desired folder
- Then it recursively copies files and folders to new folder excluding anything on the exclusion list.
- Lastly it opens up a Windows Explorer window to the destination folder that was created containing all the recently copied files and folders.

Edit: Updated to use the path specified in the comment. If this answer provided a solution to your question please mark it as the selected answer so future users can find it and use it without having to repeat questions.

Comment: Thank you!  So the path to the user's temporary folder will be odd since the person doing this operation is not the owner of the media.  Thus, I'm having to also get a service account (an admin used for scripts like these) to write the files.  The directory will look something like:  \\BAAC\homedir\username\transfer\newFolderNameByDate.hour.minute

Comment: I have updated my answer to match your destination path, please mark the answer as the solution if it provides a solution to your question.

Comment: Awesome!  I was also able to get that to work, but your version is much sleeker!  I checked this as the solution - wish I could vote it up.  Thank you again!

Comment: RATS!  The file types that need to be excluded are getting through

Comment: What exactly does your exclusion input file look like? I don't need the whole thing, but a sample including any headers would be good. I tested this code, so it shouldn't be letting things through unless I assumed wrong on your CSV contents.

Comment: When I look at it in NotePad, it has one entry per line starting with: Extension pdf doc ppt zip msi exe acm ade adp bas bat bin   And so on - no commas, nopunctuation, just like those in this, but one per line.

Comment: I would step through the script and echo back `$Exclusions` after it is set, just to make sure it returns something like "*.pdf,*.doc,*.ppt,*.zip,*.msi,*.exe" with all your desired exclusions in it. Or did you get this figured out already?

Comment: Nope haven't figured out out, but I did come across an answer here that said the recursion would not work with Exception.  I did not look that up yet.  Should each of the file types in $Exclusions have quotes, or have the *. in front?

Comment: They should not all have quotes, but they should all have a *. in front.